# Python pexpect.expect() on Telegram CLI

Tags: python, command-line-interface, pexpect

I'm trying to make a bot for Telegram on my RPi but I'm pretty new to this. I installed [Telegram Cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) and pexpect.

This is my test.py file:

```
import pexpect

telegram = pexpect.spawn('./telegram -k tg.pub')
telegram.expect("User")
telegram.send("msg Big_Boss test")
```

However this give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    telegram.expect("User*")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1451, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1466, in expect_list
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1554, in expect_loop
    raise EOF(str(err) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
```

I couldnt find any good documentation about the expect function. Basically what I am trying to do is send X when someone messages me something containing Y. But I can't get the first thing working. Simply sending a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Pexpect tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-the-pexpect-module-in-python), and some sample code:

### source

```
import pexpect

calc = pexpect.spawn('bc')
calc.expect("details")
print calc.send("1+2")
```

### output

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the tutorial and I understand it. But I still dont know why I keep getting that error ^

Comment: hmm. In your posted exception (but not code) is `telegram.expect("User*")` -- this might not be what you want. Expect uses regular expressions; the input will match `Use` and any number of `r`s.   That might be part of it.